# iTextSharp image keep pixel dimensions?

Tags: image-manipulation, itext

Lets say I have an image that has a DPI of 72 and a width/height of 100px/100px.

However when I add the image and render the PDF, the image that is displayed is bigger than 100px/100px.  How can I ensure that the when adding the image to the PDF using iTextSharp that I keep the same pixel dimensions as the original image, in this case 100px/100px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to check out the ScaleAbsolute method of the iTextSharp.text.Image, which will explicitly set the height/width of an image.  There are a couple of related methods you'll want to read up to: ScalePercent and ScaleToFit.

These methods are described in the [SourceForge iTextSharp tutorial](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch06.html) which includes samples.  See tge "Scaling and Rotating the Image" section.